# Android - where can I see the request url that is generated when setDataSource(..) is called?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to add headers to my setDataSource() method. Is there any way I could see the request itself that is sent ? I need to do this because I'd like to confirm if the url generated by setDataSource method is correctly formed. I don't however see any apis in the MediaPlayer class that can help me do this. Any direction or a solution would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For non-file media source, the framework handle it by `MediaHTTPConnection` which is a hide API. You can change its field `VERBOSE` to true to see the printed log.

Since it's not exported, we can't use it directly. The following code might helpful, but I am not sure if it works. Run it before `setDataSource()`.

```
try {
    Class mediaServiceClass = Class.forName("android.media.MediaHTTPConnection");
    Field field = mediaServiceClass.getDeclaredField("VERBOSE");
    field.setAccessible(true);

    Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

    field.setBoolean(null, true);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can refer [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/MediaHTTPConnection.java) to see the detail implementation of `MediaHTTPConnection`.